# How to auto-launch new version of ClickOnce application after auto-update?

Tags: clickonce, visual-studio-2019

I am using ClickOnce with the `Specify a minimum required version for this application` to force updates out to my organization. When a user opens the app the ClickOnce launcher automatically updates and then closes but the app never starts. The problem is that the user thinks they are running the app, they don't care about updates or what version they are running. Currently, the user needs to "ClickTwice" to actually run the app. Once for the update and once to run the new version.

**How can I get real "ClickOnce" where the user runs the app once, it updates, and then launches the new version?**

I am using the Publish GUI to force updates. Here are my settings as seen in VS:
[image]

Comment: how did you force the app to update version ? with application update dialog from publish tab or with xml ? i didn't see this problem before, it always opens to update and start the app automatically, can you update the question and add image for application update properties?

Comment: @NajiMakhoul I am using Publish tab. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Try to uncheck "Specify a minimum required"  in publish GUI dialog and modify project file in xml  , you can force update version using msbuild , see my answer here (for vb.net, but you can use it in c#) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62811939/2713855

Comment: That's a neat trick but it doesn't change the odd behavior on the client side.

Comment: did you try to reinstall the app on client side ? it must work .. i'm using it with all my apps