# VB.net application is keeping previous versions

Tags: .net, vb.net, clickonce, versioning

I have a visual basic project that is being published and increments the version number each time.

When I install a new version, it opens but as soon as the application restarts, it seems to revert back to the previous version and I cannot work out why.

Comment: did you specify the minimum version required in application properties  ?

Comment: Sounds like you might not be using the Click-once infrastructure correctly. I'm guessing something in your application "remembers" it's previously installed version, and opens that version instead of the new one. See my answer below about how to use publishing to ensure your users can install the correct version, and keep the application updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update a minimum version required when you publish the application
go to application proprties -> publish -> Updates...:

[image]

If you want to do this automatically and force the user to work on latest version only, you can update the `vbproj` file with `MSBuild`

1. In Visual Studio, right click on the project and click on `Unload Project`
2. Right click on the project and click on `Edit`
3. Copy and Paste the following code before the close `</Project>` element

   > ```
   > <Target Name="AutoSetMinimumRequiredVersion" BeforeTargets="GenerateDeploymentManifest">
   >   <FormatVersion Version="$(ApplicationVersion)" Revision="$(ApplicationRevision)">
   >     <Output PropertyName="MinimumRequiredVersion" TaskParameter="OutputVersion"  />
   >   </FormatVersion>
   >   <FormatVersion Version="$(ApplicationVersion)" Revision="$(ApplicationRevision)">
   >     <Output PropertyName="_DeploymentBuiltMinimumRequiredVersion" TaskParameter="OutputVersion"  />
   >   </FormatVersion>
   > </Target>
   > ```
4. Save and Reload the project

Comment: the users using this application are all based in different locations and not on the same network, so where should it check for updates?

Comment: how do you published the application , with ftp? or just copy the published files to some directory ?

Comment: i make an .exe from an archive and upload it to the web as a single file

Comment: so you are not publishing with clickonce ! you need to upload the *.application file (with your exe file) after you publishing using Visual studio and the user must download and install the file with "application" extension to  start the app and it will check for update automatically, see [Publish ClickOnce applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/publishing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @charlie See my answer below: You can provide a public url that points to an installation file, which can run and install the application. I've indicated what the URL to your app will be based on what you provide in the settings there. If you need to restrict access, then perhaps you can password protect that url somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a Click-once app is that it is uploaded to some URL where clients can fetch the latest version of it, automatically install it, and check for updates later. You can specify these under ***Publish*** in your project settings.

[image: Specify foler location and installation URL]

Once the correct data is provided here, you can publish your app, and have your users install it from the Installation Folder URL.

Under **Updates** (button in the pic above), you can specify whether the app should be available offline, what the minimum required version should be (**make sure to update this to force updates!**), and when the app should check for updates.

If you set this up correctly, then the application should update itself whenever a user starts it on a client, and a new version is available on the server.

PS: The full URL to download your application should then be as follows:

```
http://publicaddress.to.that.folder/YorApp/Your.Project.Name.application
```

Here `Your.Project.Name` is the name of your project in Visual Studio, and `.application` is the file extention for the installation file.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `Clean` and `Rebuild` the Project.

Comment: First try to change source code location and rebuild otherwise try this one:

Comment: remove the history and caching in Internet Options.
Go into Internet Option (also available in VS via Tools > options > Environment > Web Browser > Internet Explorer Options).
On the General tab click Settings in the Browsing History section.

On the Temporary Internet Files page select Every time I start Internet Explorer

On the History tab set the Days to keep history to 0

On the Caches and Database tab make sure Allow website caches and databases is NOT ticked.

Try to made a number of changes to files and so far they have been reflect straight away in the dynamic versions without any not

Comment: surely we shouldn't have to do this on every PC the software is installed on?

Comment: First you try in single machine, if problem is that then you need to do in all PC otherwise we look for another solution