# After clickonce updated, still old version is running

Tags: c#, windows, clickonce

I created a setup for windows application using clickonce. I installed 1.0.0 version in my local machine. Then I released new version 1.0.1 on server. After sometime, my setup updated with new version and started again. But after update, still my application runs 1.0.0 version. I'm using following code for update.

```
UpdateCheckInfo info = null;
ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
if (info.UpdateAvailable)
{
ad.Update();
Application.Restart();
}
```

Comment: Which version number are you checking? The AssemblyVersion of the application and its DLLs aren't related to the ClickOnce manifest version.

Comment: I am checking the clickonce version, not an assemble version, installation path I found both versions files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.net application is keeping previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764227/vb-net-application-is-keeping-previous-versions)

Comment: I find that I don’t need any code for ClickOnce to work.  Check your Publish settings